Are there any recorded time-of-flight (ToF) measurement data for the $H\to\gamma\gamma$ collision products at the LHC Atlas detector?
Especially, I am interested in the time-of-flight (ToF) measured recorded values of the two $\gamma$-photons (diphotons) during  $H \to\gamma\gamma$ Higgs boson detection events at the LHC Atlas detector.
If yes, any reference link or data presented herein would be helpful for my research.
Please notice I am not referring to and this should not be confused with ring-imaging Cherenkov detector measurements at LHC CERN but to the direct measurement of the propagation speed in the vacuum of the two emitted $\gamma$-photons during a Higgs boson decay. Thus, how much time these two $\gamma$-photons took during their flight from the Atlas chamber center beam collision point to the inner wall detector surface  Liquid Argon (LAr) calorimeter sensors.
This measurement dataset is crucial in my research for the detection of possible emitted dark photons during this process.

Have a look here to understand that what you are asking for cannot be done https://cds.cern.ch/record/2736135?ln=en . There is no way to determine the timing you are asking for.

@annav That is most intriguing! Thanks for this information.

Also, specifically for the ATLAS experiment date and not the CMS experiment of the previous comment: https://twiki.cern.ch/twiki/bin/view/AtlasPublic/EventDisplaysFromHiggsSearches#H

I make clear that I was a member of the CMS experiment when active ( am retired now)

@annav So, if I understood correctly extraction of specific ToF data of the individual byproducts is not possible because complexity of the experiment?

I have calculated the distance from the beam collision point to the  Liquid Argon (LAr) calorimeters surface of the ATLAS detector to 104 cm radius thus approximately a 3.3 ns ToF of the γ-photons in the vacuum?

Correction to my previous comment, the first layer of SCT is a 299mm distance from the beam thus an approximately $1ns$ ToF.  https://indico.mitp.uni-mainz.de/event/167/attachments/657/695/ATLAS_Fraueninsel_part1.pdf

The topic is more complicated, after the first layer of SCT detectors at 299mm distance from the beams' collision point the distances of the diphoton trails to the L(Ar) calorimeter outer skin surface taxed to measure the γγ photons of the Higgs, can vary from 1.04m distance in the perpendicular direction to a maximum of 3m depending on the photon's arbitrary specific  flight trail each time. See this illustration: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1j83o0EU-lOkbSS052PpGTaZg9_qSCtzB/view?usp=sharing . Source: https://cds.cern.ch/record/2281322/files/ATL-PHYS-SLIDE-2017-682.pdf
